# Where can I download the Sony hack malware (for analysis)?

Tags: malware, research

I want to analyze the Sony hack Malware.

I would like to perform my own independent analysis of this malware; where can I download this malware so I can analyze it?

Trend Micro has analyzed the malware here: http://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/news/cyber-attacks/the-hack-of-sony-pictures-what-you-need-to-know and do not make it available for other researchers.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.  It's not of general interest, but only of interest, and any answers are likely to rapidly go out of date as it's highly unlikely that this specific malware should it even ever be made openly available, would remain available for long.

Comment: How does this seem off-topic? Is there a separate stack exchange for malware analysis? The Info Sec field changes rapidly. Most things to do with security get outdated pretty quickly. How does that make this question off-topic. How is this question any different from say a question on the Shell Shock Vulnerability.

Comment: @user1529891 malware analysis is an integral part of infosec but that does not mean that that is on-topic here. "Where can I get X?" is just not a question type that is on-topic.

Comment: @user1529891 no, because this just highlights why these types of questions are a bad idea here: any answers are completely dependent on the links remaining valid.

Answer (score 3):

I looked for the malware and found it, here is the link but you have to go on the forum and download it:

```
http://malwaretips.com/threads/2014-12-11-destover-malware-7-samples.38799/
```

Go to the above link and you will see the zip file and the password for it.

Comment: zip file and password does not seem to exist anymore?